# Rails_admin, remove CKEditor actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, rails-admin

I'm using Rails_admin and I have intgrated CKEditor with ability to upload images and other files.

Now on dashboard it shows me new models:

- Assets

  - Attachment files
  - Pictures

Also it created 3 ruby files inside my models folder.

All of them has CRUD actions. I wanted to remove `create` and `update` actions from them, only leaving `show` and `delete`, because they will be added via `CKEditor` itself.

In `rails_admin.rb` where `config.actions do` is written, I have added this:

```
 edit do
  except %w(Asset AttachmentFile Picture)
 end
```

When I start my application, thay still has `create` and `update` actions.

Why?

Comment: According to my new understanding, it seems that your config is correct, but you said "ckeditor models", you're just using ckeditor as a rich text editor for the models right?, or is there a new way I'm not aware of.

Comment: If you go to this link https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CKEditor. There will be instructions of how to integrate CKEditor for rails_admin. During the integration it will create image, file uploaders and models that represent these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution. In my `rails_admin.rb` file I needed to write this:

```
 new do
  except %w(Ckeditor::Asset Ckeditor::AttachmentFile Ckeditor::Picture)
 end

edit do
  except %w(Ckeditor::Asset Ckeditor::AttachmentFile Ckeditor::Picture)
end
```